# Solve the following probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question: ** A speaks truth in $75%$ of the cases, while B in $90%$ of the cases. In what percent of cases, are they likely to contradict each other in stating the same fact? Do you think that statement of B is true?

**progress: **  In the first case the answer is $30%$. I have problem in the second case. Can anyone explain me the second case, how can I calculate whether B's statement is true or not?

Comment: You should note that you are assuming that $A$ and $B$ lie (or speak the truth) independently.

Comment: To your second question:  There are two states that contribute to that $.3$ probability.  Namely (A lies, B True) and (A true, B lies).  Let $p_1$ be the probability of the first and $p_2$ the probability of the second.  Then you are asking about $\frac {p_1}{p_1+p_2}$.

Comment: @lulu what can I conclude about B from you answer?

Comment: My hint was pretty strong!   Given that they contradict, the probability that $B$ is true is $\frac {p_1}{p_1+p_2}$ while the probability that $A$ is true is $\frac {p_2}{p_1+p_2}$.  Just compute both and compare.

Comment: @lulu oh! I see. It is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

P(A speaks the truth and B tells a lie) = $75/100 * ( 1 - 90/100) = 75/100 * 10/100 = 3 / 40$

P(B speaks the truth and B tells a lie) = $90/100 * ( 1 - 75/100) = 90/100 * 25/100 = 9 / 40$

Required percentage = $( 3/40 + 9/40) * 100 = 30$

Case 2:

No, the statement of B may not be true always.

Comment: @KS Why statement of B is not true?

Comment: As you can see B speaks truth only in 90% cases. And in 10% cases he lies. So there's a possibility that B may be lie.

Comment: And I wrote in answer that B may be lie. And I have seen same type of question and answer in some book.